# How do I propagate schema types to different files on fastify?

Tags: node.js, typescript, fastify

I am trying out Fastify with Typescript and I would like to have separation of concerns. Specifically, I want to separate my schema from my controller and routers. However, I do not manage to pass around the schema types easily.

My server creation is as follows:

```
import Fastify from 'fastify';
import { JsonSchemaToTsProvider } from '@fastify/type-provider-json-schema-to-ts';
import balanceRoute from './features/balance/route';

const createServer = () => {
  const server = Fastify({ logger: true }).withTypeProvider<JsonSchemaToTsProvider>();

  server.get('/healthz', async (request, reply) => {
    return reply.code(200).send({
      data: {
        status: 'OK'
      }
    });
  })

  server.register(balanceRoute, { prefix: '/balance' });

  return server;
}
```

My route is:

```
const route = async (server: FastifyTyped) => {
  server.get(
    '/:address',
    {
      schema: GetBalanceSchema
    },
    getBalanceController
  );
};
```

My controller is:

```
export const getBalanceController = async (req: FastifyRequest, res: FastifyReply) => {
  console.log('Within get balance handler');
  const address = req.params.address; // PROBLEM IS HERE
  const currentBalance = await getBalance('', '');
  res.send({ hello: 'hello' });
};
```

My schema is as follows:

```
import { FastifySchema } from 'fastify';

export const GetBalanceSchema: FastifySchema  = {
  params: {
    address: { type: 'string' }
  },
  querystring: {
    chainID: { type: 'string' }
  },
  response: {
    200: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        data: {
          type: 'string'
        }
      }
    }
  }
} as const;
```

In the controller code, I cannot get Typescript to infer that req.params has an address field. Also, if I move the controller within the route it does not help neither.

Any clue about how to get this working in an easy way?

Thank you in advance and regards

Answer (score 0):

That's because you've given your schema an explicit type annotation `FastifySchema`, which overrides the `as const`. You can try removing the explicit type annotation:

```
export const GetBalanceSchema = {
...
} as const;
```

Or not using `as const`:

```
export const GetBalanceSchema: FastifySchema = {
...
};
```

Maybe even using a utility function to enforce the type while retaining the original structure of the object:

```
function schema<S extends FastifySchema>(schema: S): S { return schema; }

export const GetBalanceSchema = schema({
...
});
```

But in TypeScript 4.9, we've got a new [`satisfies`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#the-satisfies-operator) operator, that we can use like this:

```
export const GetBalanceSchema = {
...
} satisfies FastifySchema;
```

Comment: Thanks! Though it did not work, even if I place all within the route schema structure is not passed. I think it is related with "type providers" as far as I have seen so far

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the controller file:

```
export const getBalanceController = async (req: FastifyRequest<
    RouteGenericInterface,
    RawServerDefault,
    IncomingMessage,
    typeof GetBalanceSchema,
    JsonSchemaToTsProvider
  >, res: FastifyReply) => {
  console.log('Within get balance handler');
  const address = req.params.address; // PROBLEM IS HERE
  const currentBalance = await getBalance('', '');
  res.send({ hello: 'hello' });
};
```

and remove the `: FastifySchema` typing in the schema file:

```
export const GetBalanceSchema  = {
  params: {
    address: { type: 'string' }
  },
  querystring: {
    chainID: { type: 'string' }
  },
  response: {
    200: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        data: {
          type: 'string'
        }
      }
    }
  }
} as const;
```